# How do I create a stacked bar graph with Pandas and Plotly that is sorted by the total heights of the columns, not just the largest individual value?

Tags: pandas, visualization, plotly-express, stacked-bar-chart, django-pandas

I have a Django model that contains all the songs all users have added to the playlist of a service. I want to display the 20 most requested songs with a stacked bar chart, with colors showing the different users who have added the song.

My problem is that I have been unable to sort the Plotly graph by the total height of the Y-axis. Instead it sorts the columns by the highest individual value (the amount of times the user with most requests of given song has requested it.).

[The current result of stacked bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9TQK.png)

**This is what my django models look like:**

```
    class Song(models.Model):
        adders = models.ManyToManyField(Syncer)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
        video_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        def __str__(self):
            return(f"Song: {self.name}, adders: {self.adders}")
        
    class QueueEntry(models.Model):
        entry_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(Syncer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
        added_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

**I get the names of the 20 most played songs in the django view with this**

`most_played = Song.objects.annotate(times_added=Count('queueentry', distinct=True)).order_by("-times_added")[1:20]`

and I use that to get a QueueEntry queryset that contains all individual song requests of the 20 most played songs.

```
    song_ids = most_played.values_list('id', flat=True)
    
    all= QueueEntry.objects.filter(song__id__in=song_ids)
```

**Then I create a panda dataframe using django_pandas.io and perform grouping and aggregating**

```
from django_pandas.io import read_frame
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = read_frame(all)

    song_counts = df.groupby(['song', 'user']).agg(item_count=('entry_id', 'count')).reset_index()
    print(song_counts)
```

the print(song_counts) outputs the data in a seemingly correct order

| index | song | user | itemcount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | oksong | mike | 3 |
| 2 | oksong | jack | 1 |
| 3 | goodsong | sarah | 2 |
| 4 | badsong | anna | 1 |

**And finally I create a stacked bar chart.**

`fig = px.bar( song_counts, x='song', y='item_count', color='user', color_continuous_scale='blues', #color_continuous_midpoint=6, title=f'Songs')`

Where is the problem in my code? Why aren't the bars being sorted by their TOTAL height (all individual users itemcounts of the song added together)

Comment: It is not automatically sorted, see [this reference](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#bar-chart-with-sorted-or-ordered-categories).